# Link to Grouping Categories

Tags: 2013, javascript, document-library, custom-list, grouping

I would like to create a link that will take me directly to the grouping section in a list.  This is similar to page anchors on a word document.  Is this possible?

Update: This is a custom list not a wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to achieve this

1. Using anchor tag you can specify which section of the page it should scroll to
2. Using JavaScript you can find the group element. The scroll to that element by handling the click event.

Comment: Can this be done on a custom list or document library? Thanks

Comment: Yes both will eventually get rendered as HTML.. And you can add a script editor webpart and manipulate as required.